# Make a second movie clip out of a movie clip in Flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, animation, movieclip

sorry if there is a ridiculously basic answer to this, but this is my dilemma.

I have a movie clip of an animated character for a kids game i'm making at Uni. I need a movie clip, same animations, just with a crown and a few alterations to him, within a movie clip so the crown moves with his head.

Is there anyway to edit my first movie clip (example name char_1), add the crown and save it as another (char_2) without changing char_1?

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you right-click the movieclip on the stage, you can select 'Duplicate symbol'. This will create a copy, however, any child movieclips will be shared with the original, so any edits to child movieclips will be reflected in the original movieclip.

To get around the above issue, if it's an issue for you then do this:

1. In the library, right-click the movieclip and choose 'copy'
2. Open a new FLA and paste the movieclip into the new library. All the associated movieclips and assets will be copied too.
3. Create a new folder and place everything inside it. This folder can now be copied back to the original FLA without overwriting any of the original movieclips.